# Paypal Sandbox payment not shown in activity or in IPN list

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am quite new to PayPal payments.

I am trying to make a sandbox payment using the "Server Side Express Checkout using REST" method (from here:  https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server). Everything seems to work fine apart from that when I use my buyer account, I see the amount paid being reduced, but it never seems to reach the business account! I have made several payments all with the same result! No payments received shown in my sandbox account activity, and also, although I have enabled IPN notifications, I see none of those payments in my IPN list.

For my backend I use Python, and I follow the instructions shown here: 
For creating and executing the payment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK

When I retrieve these payments with a python script 
(as shown here here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/payment/all.py). The status of these payments is shown as "approved" ("state": "approved") (While before execution the payment it was ("state": "created")...

I have the feeling that that is the reason why I don't see them in my activity list or in my IPN list, because the "state" should be "completed" or something similar! But how can I do that? I can't find any documentation on the matter and I don't understand why after the payment execution Python script finishes,  the "state" is not "completed"!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: REST API transactions will not trigger an IPN.  REST uses [Webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/?mark=webhooks) instead.

Comment: @halfer I don't understand your comment, since I didn't put the word "urgent" or any other with similar meaning to my comment.

Comment: @AndrewAngell Thank you for your reply, still, apart from the IPN not showing though, I see no payment recorded or money deposited to my sandbox account and that's my main problem. Shouldn't I be able to see the amount paid in my balance? Especially since the transactions are there and can be retrieved with the python script I have posted in my initial question?

Comment: @halfer Maybe I did, I don't remember since I wrote that some days ago and I was really tired and sleepless from trying to figure this out!
I am sorry if I did something wrong, I would appreciate though if I was given the chance to edit and correct my own comments, because if I won't notice the change I cannot know if the meaning of my question is being altered without my consent.
If you let me know of anything inappropriate that I might post here and I won't comply, then by all means I agree I must be even banned, but please do not alter my posts without notifying me first !

Comment: @halfer To avoid any misunderstanding, I really appreciate your advice, and my comment is a mere suggestion, similar to yours, because, if you change posts without their authors knowing, this could also create problems!
I might have put the "urgent" phrase because I actually have a very short deadline, and it never crossed my mind that characterizing my need to as "urgent", might create problems (I became aware of this after you noted it to me, so I didn't know such "rules" apply here). 
I'll try to refrain from such mistakes and I thank you for letting me know about it!

Comment: Maybe it's a cultural difference but sincerely I find nothing wrong with stating that I would appreciate any quick help for an urgent matter!
I know that people here (like elsewhere) offer their help voluntarily and on their spare time, I also have do the same, but I am not offended if I see that someone who tries to achieve their deadline states that a problem is of urgent nature! If I don't force or threaten someone to answer unwillingly, it's just a factual statement and call for not overlooking an inquiry if you have an answer or an idea that might help!
I do appreciate your time though!